# How to use OpenLayer to show custom Markers on Map

Tags: html, css, openlayers

I am using openLayer in order to show markers on a map.
I have this following function,

```
const clusterMemberStyle = (clusterMember: any) => {
      const record = clusterMember.values_.record;
      return new Style({
        zIndex: 200,
        geometry: clusterMember.values_.geometry,
        image: new Icon({
          src:
            "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," +
            encodeURIComponent(
              renderSVG(
                getColor(record.propertyTypes[0]),
                `$${abbreviate(record.priceFrom, 2)}`
              )
            ),
          scale: 0.2,
        }),
      });
    };
```

In this function svg is being used to create a marker like such,

[Marker 1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSjku.png)

I am trying to add an image inside the svg

[Marker 2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amrQl.png)

I was able to acheive the same using this SVG code.

```
<svg width="96" height="80" viewBox="0 0 96 80" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_dd_5223_519053)">
    <circle cx="6" cy="6" r="6" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 10 66)" fill="#2398EC"/>
    <path d="M14 34H84V54C84 58.4183 80.4183 62 76 62H22C17.5817 62 14 58.4183 14 54V34Z" fill="#2398EC"/>
    <path d="M14.75 34.75H83.25V54C83.25 58.0041 80.0041 61.25 76 61.25H22C17.9959 61.25 14.75 58.0041 14.75 54V34.75Z" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.1" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <path d="M83 34.5H83.5V34V21C83.5 15.201 78.799 10.5 73 10.5H25C19.201 10.5 14.5 15.201 14.5 21V34V34.5H15H83Z" fill="#1E252B" stroke="#2398EC"/>
    <text x="28" y="52" fill="white" font-family="Arial" font-size="15" font-weight="700">$929k</text>
    <image x="25" y="12" href="https://cdn.realestateview.com.au/images/listing/160-30/4e4ae83f0f524e6d8e18434ee746adab.png" height="25" width="50"/>
    <mask id="mask0_5223_519053" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="21" y="19" width="53" height="11">
      <rect x="21" y="19" width="53" height="10.6828"/>
    </mask>
    <g mask="url(#mask0_5223_519053)">
      <rect x="19.0947" y="17.5098" width="57.1406" height="14.6578" fill="sss"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter0_dd_5223_519053" x="-2" y="0" width="98" height="80" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
      <feOffset dy="2"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="6"/>
      <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0.3 0"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_5223_519053"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
      <feOffset dy="1"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
      <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0.08 0"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in2="effect1_dropShadow_5223_519053" result="effect2_dropShadow_5223_519053"/>
      <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect2_dropShadow_5223_519053" result="shape"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

But the problem is OpenLayer does not go on to fetch SVG from a URL rather it is looking for just pure binary code in order to generate the marker.

Any tech that can be used over here in order to acheive the funcitonality can be really helpful. I have also tried creating the UI with HTML-CSS but openLayer actually looks for HTMLImgElement for the same. and does not except any HTML code.

I have tried HTML-CSS way to do it and also tried the svg way both do not work.

Comment: As long as you do not need to declutter you can use a style array with both images https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-forked-vp7fhf?file=/main.js and adjust the scales and anchors as needed.  Otherwise draw the images to a canvas and create a data url from that.

Comment: @Mike how can i handle onClick event on overlay which I am using on openLayer in map